# Finding coordinates of maximum values of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find a way to find the sets of coordinates of the maximum value/s in a matrix of size [8,8], where the values in the matrix vary from 0 to 6 (generated through the rest of the script/function).

i.e. a matrix of zeros(8,8) where the value 1 is in [3,3], [3,5] and [5,3].
and I want to get returned something along the lines of ([3,3],[3,5],[5,3])
I have tried using things such as ind2sub, etc but with no luck (I keep getting things returned like [I,J] = [  [0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0]    ,    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]  ])

Any ideas?
If more clarification is needed, just point out where you need it and I'd be glad to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you've been having with `max` so far is because it operates on one dimension.  If you call it on a matrix, using its default parameters, it will return a single maximum element (and indices) for each column of the matrix.  In your case, you want *all* maximums, and the global maximum at that.

Try this:

```
[I,J] = find(M == max(M(:)))
```

First, `max(M(:))` finds the maximum element, then we construct a logical matrix `M == max(M(:))` showing which elements are the maximum.  Finally, you can use `find` to get the co-ordinates of those (if necessary).